How do you properly setup i18n with nextjs?
I've read through multiple articles and documentations and I still can't quite figure out how I'm supposed to be doing this. I mainly followed to vercel next-intl guide and the official nextjs documentation.
My pages are all under /pages/<...> together with my _app.tsx looking like this:
import {NextIntlClientProvider} from 'next-intl';
import {useRouter} from 'next/router';

export default function App({Component, pageProps}) {
    const router = useRouter();

    return (
        <NextIntlClientProvider
            locale={router.locale}
            timeZone="Europe/Vienna"
            messages={pageProps.messages}
        >
            <Component {...pageProps} />
        </NextIntlClientProvider>
    );
}

My /pages/index.tsx looks like this:
'use client';
import '../app/globals.css'
import '../styles/page.css'
import { useTranslation } from 'next-i18next';

export async function getStaticProps(context: { locale: any; }) {
    return {
        props: {
            messages: (await import(`../public/locales/${context.locale}/translation.json`)).default
        }
    };
}
const Index: React.FC = () => {
    const { t } = useTranslation();
   
    return (
        <div className="main">
            <div>
                <div>
                    <h1>{t('homepage_welcome')}</h1>
<...>

My next.config.js looks like this:
module.exports = {
    i18n: {
        locales: ['en', 'de'],
        defaultLocale: 'en',
    },
}

What is it that I'm missing?
Edit: I do end up with an react-i18next:: You will need to pass in an i18next instance by using initReactI18next.

For clarification, the JSON files are in /public/locales//translation.json as shown above

the t function has to find a key 'homepage_welcome' in a JSON file with the translation value. I din't see it in the provided code. I only see a messages props in the Provider. Also, you can add debug: true in the i18n init method to help you debug your code.
